# I am trying to execute pip install fastapi[all] but it is not working

Tags: api, performance

I want to install Fast API to my mac by entering pip install fastapi[all], it errors.

```
kanta@Kantas-MacBook-Air fastapi % pip install "fastapi[all]"
zsh: command not found: pip
kanta@Kantas-MacBook-Air fastapi % pip install fastapi[all] 
zsh: no matches found: fastapi[all]
kanta@Kantas-MacBook-Air fastapi % pip install fastapi[all]
zsh: no matches found: fastapi[all]
kanta@Kantas-MacBook-Air fastapi % pip install 'fastapi[all]'
zsh: command not found: pip
kanta@Kantas-MacBook-Air fastapi %
```

I think it is because I am using a mac. Is there a workaround?

Comment: On Mac and Linux `pip` don't get installed along with python. To install `pip`, you can check out this article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-pip-in-macos/

Answer (score 3):

Please try :

```bash
pip3 install 'fastapi[all]'
```

Comment: This worked, but why? eg why pip3 and not just "pip"?

Answer (score 0):

You can reach pip via `-m` flag:

```
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
```

```
python3 -m pip install "fastapi[all]"
```

Note: use `python3` or any other alias for your version e.g. `python3.10`.

Also, I may recommend creating venv for your project.

```
python3 -m pip install virtualenv
python3 -m virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install "fastapi[all]"
```